# The local variable string may not have been initialized peculiarity

Tags: java, string, object

From what I know, initalizing a variable is when you set a value to it. For example:

```
String s;        // declaring the String (throws an error if you use in conditionals)
String s = null; // declaring and then initializing the String (no error)
```

However, when a `String` is declared, isn't it automatically initialized to `null`? Therefore, the compiler shouldn't throw an error.

I also noticed that `String s = new String();` does not produce any errors when used with conditionals but `String s;` does. I thought these two statements were essentially the same thing and the latter was even encouraged over the former.

My questions are, why does `String s = new String();` work but not `String s;` (when using conditionals to set their value)? Shouldn't both strings be automatically initalized to `null`, therefore not causing an error?

Bonus question: Since `String` objects are automatically initialized to `null`, why does the following code print an empty `String`?

```
String s  = new String();
System.out.println(s);
```

**EDIT: Apparently I don't think straight when I'm tired. This whole question is a mess, I have no idea what I was thinking. Apologies to those who had to try and understand it.**

**Also, the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)on default values:**

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

**Which answers the above question.**

Comment: Your question is no different from others. A String is initialized to `null` **if** it is declared in the class. And `new String()` creates a String object as you would expect, not null. Nothing unusual to see here.

Comment: String s = new String(); is equivalent to String s = new String(""); so s is not null in the first case.

Comment: Voting to close with just one of many duplicates of this question. The "bonus" question is a non-question and doesn't need a duplicate as it is answered in any intro to Java book first chapter.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Apparently I don't think straight when I'm tired. Apologies for the duplicate/stupid questions.

Answer (score 5):

> *However, when a String is declared, isn't it automatically initialized to null? Therefore, the compiler shouldn't throw an error.*

No, this is only true for class level variables. Local variables are not assigned a default value, but needs to be explicitly initialized.

> *Since String objects are automatically initialized to null, why does the following code print an empty String?*

`String` *objects* are never initialized to `null`. Class level `String` *references* on the other hand, are.